# Run-time Error 1004 unable to set the visible property of the DrawingObjects class

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

So the code was working fine until a recent update, however my IT team isn't able to figure out what is causing the error. I am wondering if there is a Reference I am missing or if it's something else. The main code is in Sheet 1 and the Function is in Module 1.

I've done some research with the references and everything currently the following are selected: Visual Basic for Applications, MS Excel 16.0 object library, OLE Automation, MS Office 16.0 Object Library, MS Forms 2.0 Object Library, MS VBScript Reg Exp 1.0 and 5.5, MS Outlook 16.0 Object Library.

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem

Set rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
'Only the visible cells in the selection
Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
'You can also use a fixed range if you want
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:H15").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
           vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = "compliance.data@rheem.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "NEW VENDOR SETUP"
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Display   'or use .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

MODULE 1 CODE:

```
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

The Error appears on `.DrawingObjects.Visible = True` and I'm not sure why.

Comment: If you remove/comment out the `On Error Resume Next`, do you get that same error?

Comment: Yes, the same error on the same line appears. and thank you for the edit :)

Comment: Do you have "break on all errors" set in your Excel VBA options?  You should probably switch that to "break in class module" or you will get errors even in the presence of `On Error Resume Next`  Check under *Tools >> Options >> General >> Error trapping*

Comment: @TimWilliams - I was wondering how OP could still get an error with the `Resume Next`...

Comment: "break on all errors" was selected. I have switched it to "Break in class module" should I default all my workbooks that are set up like that to the class module?

Comment: I think that's a global setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess, but worked on a spreadsheet for me.

If your sheet doesn't have any drawing objects, you can get an error.  Try replacing that bit with:

```
On Error Resume Next
If .DrawingObjects.Count > 0 Then
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
End If    
On Error GoTo 0
```

I also would probably remove the `On Error` bits, but see if the above works...